# Scale images of different size using Bootstrap/CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a web application layout like this, styled with Bootstrap:

```
------------------------
|        Header        |
------------------------
|     Display Area     |
------------------------
```

The Header is a collection of control elements (mostly buttons) and therefore almost of same height.

The Display Area contains the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://localhost/api/currentImage" />
  </div>
</div>
```

`http://localhost/api/currentImage` returns an image. The image's size always differs: sometimes the width is bigger than height, sometimes vice versa.

Now I'd like to scale the image in that way that it uses as much as possible of the available Display without "overflowing". By overflowing, I mean that there is never a need to show a horizontal or vertical scroll bar because the image is too wide or too high. Right now, `<img class="img-fluid" ...` only scales the width correctly.

How can I achieve this using Bootstrap/CSS?

Comment: So you want the image to *cover* the space? So like the image can get cut off as long as it does not causes a scroll bar to appear?

Comment: No, the image should fill all the available space without being cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap will let you resize images with its `img-fluid` class, but if you need to make the image cover the entire space you would have to write your own CSS, you could make use of the `object-fit` property to set the image to fill the container, while maintaining its aspect ratio and clipping off if necessary;

As you can see in the example below, the image is narrow, but it will fill the entire container even if it has to expand to do so.

EDIT: Included two more examples with `fill` and `contain` so you can see how their behavior changes.

```css
header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

section {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

img {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  width: 100%;
  /* This is just to remove a blank space at the bottom of the image */
  display: block;
}

img.cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}

img.contain {
  object-fit: contain;
}

img.fill {
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<header>
  This is a header
</header>

<section>
  <img class="cover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x700" />
</section>

<section>
  <img class="contain" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x700" />
</section>

<section>
  <img class="fill" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x700" />
</section>
```

Comment: You're my hero of the day - works like a charm! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a predefined classes for responsive image. Check the following class,

`.img-responsive`   *Makes an image responsive (will scale nicely to the parent element)*

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img class="img-fluid img-responsive" src="http://localhost/api/currentImage" />
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: This does not work. It seems that `img-responsive` was the predecessor of `img-fluid`